# Who made this comment about Brexit and in what context?

Tags: brexit

I heard a quote on the BBC a few months ago.  The gist of it was "Brexit will destroy Britain but not leaving will destroy the Conservative party"

Who said this, and what was the exact quote?

Comment: Don’t downvote the question merely because you disagree with the content of the quote.

Comment: Cameron most likely engineered the referendum on Brexit because arguing over it was 'destroying the Conservative party'.

Comment: BBC radio or TV? which program? male or female speaker, North or Southern accent? who was the interviewer.  Any details can help.

Comment: The Today program on radio 4.  I don't remember the accent.  I don't remember the interviewer

Answer (score 3):

Possibly [James Chapman on Today](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p05c3n0p)

> The Conservative Party brand has now been damaged to such an extent that the party won't be elected again or ever get a majority ... The hard Brexit plan that Mrs May is pursuing is going to take our economy off a cliff, is going to make Black Wednesday look like a picnic. And when that happens, the Conservative Party will never be in power again...[sucessfully leaving the EU] is undeliverable and will be a calamity for our country

The context was that he was proposing that a new centre-right party with a Pro-EU policy should be set up. James Chapman is a former Tory Aide.

Comment: Are you sure? The OP is looking for a quote about how *not leaving* the EU would destroy the Conservative party; Chapman seems to be saying that *leaving* the EU will destroy the Conservative party. (Both assertions may in fact be true; one could argue not leaving would destroy them immediately, and leaving will destroy them later.)

Comment: yeah, @RoyalCanadianBandit is correct.  The quote was saying that *not leaving* is destruction for the Conservatve Party.  James Chapman is emphasising leaving as a thing that would destroy the Conservative Party

Comment: Fair enough, not a perfect match, it could have been a mis-remembered quote.  I'll leave this answer here, to avoid others suggesting Chapman.